# 9 Posukim in Kriyas Hatorah

Tags: riddle, torah-reading

Which Laining has only 9 posukim?

Comment: Some communities repeat the last verse on Purim to get 10 verses total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That of Purim morning.

Normally we don't want to be "cheap" and do the bare minimum of 9 verses, so every other reading has 10 or more; but the subject matter for Purim morning ([Amalek](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=2&CHAPTER=17#C1292)'s attack, Exodus 17:8-16) is so tightly, neatly self-contained in those 9 verses that it really didn't make sense to "bleed" into a different subject by adding a few more verses.